# ffmpeg does not recognize used codec in any way

Tags: python, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am using **ffmpeg-python** to combine video and audio in my program but for one video file I constantly get this error:

```
ffmpeg version N-55702-g920046a Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on Aug 21 2013 18:10:00 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC)
configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
libavutil      52. 42.100 / 52. 42.100
libavcodec     55. 29.100 / 55. 29.100
libavformat    55. 14.101 / 55. 14.101
libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
libavfilter     3. 82.100 /  3. 82.100
libswscale      2.  5.100 /  2.  5.100
libswresample   0. 17.103 /  0. 17.103
libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000000000073cb40] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: none (av01 / 0x31307661), 2560x1440, 5427 kb/s): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
temp/Above NYC - Filmed in 12K.mp4: could not find codec parameters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Family/PycharmProjects/8-bit Downloader/class_8_bit.py", line 4, in <module>
    ffmpeg.output(v, "temp/hello.mp4").run()
  File "C:\Users\Family\PycharmProjects\8-bit Downloader\venv\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 325, in run
    raise Error('ffmpeg', out, err)
ffmpeg._run.Error: ffmpeg error (see stderr output for detail)
```

It just doesn't recognize it. I know that the codec is **av01** I have tried passing it in as the **vcodec** keyword but nothing would work. I tried going to cmd directly and adding to the 'analyzeduration' and 'probsize' but nothing seems to work. How can I fix this? My code:

```
import ffmpeg

# I have tried passing absolute paths instead of relative ones too, still not working
input_video = ffmpeg.input("temp/Above NYC - Filmed in 12K.mp4")
input_audio = ffmpeg.input("temp/audio_temp 1.webm")
full_path = "temp/New.mp4"
out = ffmpeg.output(input_video, input_audio, full_path, vcodec='copy', acodec='aac', strict='experimental')
out.run(overwrite_output=True)
```

Comment: N.B. The `vcodec`/`c:v` parameter is for outputs, not inputs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your `ffmpeg` was not built with AV1 support. Neither `--enable-libdav1d` nor `--enable-libaom` appear in the configuration. It's also really old (a 2.0 dev build from 2013).

You can confirm with the `ffmpeg -codecs` command, and look for a line like this

> DEV.L. av1                  Alliance for Open Media AV1 (decoders: libdav1d libaom-av1 )

If it's missing, or there's no `D`, then it will not work.

Note that you have a shared build (`--disable-static --enable-shared`), so you'll also need to have the libraries installed separately, even if they were enabled.

---

> Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options

This won't work in this case. It's already found the parameters – `(av01 / 0x31307661), 2560x1440, 5427 kb/s` – but doesn't know what to do with them.

Comment: I didn't install ffmpeg directly, I just installed the python wrapper (ffmpeg-python) and I guess it installed it for me and you were right, av1 was not in the codecs. My question is how can I update my ffmpeg and if I do so will it still work with ffmpeg-python or should I use subprocess then? Because after I am done with my program I would like to publish it and maybe the user's computer does not have ffmpeg

Comment: Come to think of it I believe that a python AI program that I installed used ffmpeg and it may have installed it for me. Anyway, how can I update my ffmpeg?